# Error running "ign gazebo shapes.org" from tutorial

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Ubuntu 22.04.
I’ve installed gazebo garden using Binary installation on Ubuntu instructions from this page: https://gazebosim.org/docs/garden/install_ubuntu

Then when I run the command "ign gazebo shapes.org" I get the following response:
"Command 'ign' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo apt install ignition-tools".

After installation of "ignition-tools" I get the following error: "I cannot find any available 'ign' command:
* Did you install any ignition library?
* Did you set the IGN_CONFIG_PATH environment variable?
E.g.: export IGN_CONFIG_PATH=$HOME/local/share/ignition"

I also tried to install "libignition-gazebo" from this page: https://gazebosim.org/api/gazebo/6.3/install.html - no luck.

What is this "ign" command, and how can I install it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/28634/error-running-%22ign-gazebo-shapes.org%22-from-tutorial/) by [Vol](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/120345/vol/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2022-12-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

If you're using Gazebo Garden. You should use the [`Garden` version of the tutorials](https://gazebosim.org/docs/garden/gui).

The `ign gazebo` command was deprecated in favor of `gz sim`

See: https://gazebosim.org/docs/garden/migration_from_ignition for details on this migration.

TL;DR use `gz sim shapes.sdf`

---

Originally posted by [alex-ssom](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/107491/alex-ssom/) with karma: 16 on 2022-12-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0